# How to make array by checking object property in firebase?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I have a list of users in firebase database and I want to make an array of all users whose `isDonor` value is `true`. How can I accomplish that?
[image: firebase database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
ref.orderByChild("isDonor").equalTo(true).once("value").then((results) => {
  results.forEach((snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
  });
});
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: can u please breifly explan this?

Comment: After reading the document I linked, what isn't clear about the code I shared?

Comment: the issue is I can't render data. I have created an array and pushing each obect is it.
so array look like this in console`[{"isDonor": true, "name": "Nadi", "photo": "https://gre", "uid": "2ZE"}, {"email": "mmaz", "isDonor": true, "name": "Mz", "photo": "https://gra", "uid": "Cb"}]` but when i render it i get notthing on screen
here is code `{donorsData.map((v, i) => {
          return <Text key={i}>{v.name}</Text>;
        })}`

Comment: sorry about that. forgot to do it.